# Display MQ listener status usning Ansible not working

Tags: ansible, ibm-mq, ansible-facts

```
---
- hosts: all
  become_user: mqm
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Execute a MQ Command
      shell: 
        cmd:  "echo 'DISPLAY LSSTATUS(TCP) STATUS' | runmqsc QMGR"
        chdir: /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc
      register: mqstat

    - debug: 
        var: mqstat.stdout_lines
```

**Error: **

```
TASK [Execute a MQ Command] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [QMGR]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to xyz.pqr.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UASQnG/ansible_module_command.py\", line 213, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UASQnG/ansible_module_command.py\", line 152, in main\r\n    os.chdir(chdir)\r\nOSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what it is that you're trying to do? With only some lines and the error it will be difficult for other users to help you.

Comment: This playbook will be used to retrieve the listener status of the Queue Manager.
The basic method which we as MQ Administrator follow is to login into the server, switch user to 'mqm' and execute the following command.
Command:
echo 'DISPLAY LSSTATUS(TCP) STATUS' | runmqsc QMGR

And we receive the status in the following lines which I need to print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> chdir: /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc

If this is supposed to be the directory to execute the command in, runmqsc is not a directory name so isnt it supposed to be simply chdir: /opt/mqm/bin. In addition from the comments, remember that if you pipe to runmqsc, then runmqsc has to be on the path. If it is not, then you need to fully qualify it, meaning try:

> ```
>   shell: 
>     cmd:  "echo 'DISPLAY LSSTATUS(TCP) STATUS' | ./runmqsc QMGR"
>     chdir: /opt/mqm/bin
> ```

or

> ```
>   shell: 
>     cmd:  "echo 'DISPLAY LSSTATUS(TCP) STATUS' | /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMGR"
>     chdir: /opt/mqm/bin
> ```

Comment: And indeed the error in the question says that too: `[Errno 20] Not a directory: '/opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc'\r\n"`

Comment: fatal: [QMGR]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo 'DISPLAY LSSTATUS(TCP) STATUS' | runmqsc QMGR", "delta": "0:00:00.010684", "end": "2020-07-03 03:24:18.563220", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2020-07-03 03:24:18.552536", "stderr": "/bin/sh: runmqsc: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: runmqsc: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Comment: If its not on the path then running it will fail as per your error, ie command not found. Instead either fully qualify the command or highlight it is in the current directory because of the chdir - on Unix the current directory is not automatically searched for programs unlike on say Windows... I've edited my answer to make it clearer